# Pocketsphinx on Android failed to find acoustic model definition mdef

Tags: android, ant, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I have copied so file in libs folder and sync folder and assets.lst file in the assets.I also added `pocketsphinx-android-0.8-nolib.jar` to the application. 
I also added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

permissions to the manifest file.

Then I added code for set up `SpechRecognizer`

```
private void setUpRecognizer(){
    Assets assets = new Assets(context);
    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
    File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
    recognizer = defaultSetup()
        .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
        .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
        .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)
        .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);
    File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
    recognizer = defaultSetup()
        .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
        .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
        .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)
        .getRecognizer();
    recognizer.addListener(this);
    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
    File menuGrammer = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/menu.gram");
    recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammer);
    File digitGrammer = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/digits.gram");
    recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitGrammer);
    File languageModel = new File(modelsDir, "lm/weather.dmp");
    recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);
}
```

After running the application, I am getting the exception:

> 08-26 13:42:38.301: E/cmusphinx(14405): ERROR: "acmod.c", line 90: Folder '/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.perscitussln.sherbet/files/sync/hmm/en-us-semi' does not contain acoustic model definition 'mdef'

Can anyone help me to solve this problem or give me some advice?

Comment: Why spam SoF and CMU Sphinx forum rather than read the wiki carefully? If you can read English, you should understand that the error is due to a missing file. So put it there by hand or use synchronizing system from the demo application.

Comment: I think it is giving error due to missing md5 files. I manually put the md5 files but the application is not able to read those files.

Comment: You __do not__ need .md5 files if you put your model files to the target device manually. Forget about .md5. This is a smart copying system, but if you can't understand how it works barely you'll be able to make your application work properly.

Comment: The library itself copy the model files to the sdcard and I can see the files on the sdcard. But still the application gives error in finding the file on physical path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
   File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
   recognizer = defaultSetup()
        .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
```

Must be changed to

```
   File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
   recognizer = defaultSetup()
        .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
```

or to this:

```
    recognizer = defaultSetup()
         .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "models/hmm/en-us-semi"))
```

Take care next time.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay for upvote and yes for solving the issue.

Comment: Hi Nickolay, can you help me in _reducing the sensitivity_ of the sppech recognition in the application.